# Is there an open source or other equilvent to Android Sync Manager?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sync, samsung-galaxy-tab, backup, file-management

I am looking any suggestions of an an open source package or web software that I can manage both my Android devices (Galaxy 10.1 tab/Galaxy S Smartphone.  My computer OS is Ubuntu.  I want to be able to back up my devices and manage my files on my PC. I have tried Airdroid with limited success.  I current have the ability to view and manage my devices as data store devices.

Comment: Ubuntu One may help you... https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/android/. It syncs your files and music.

Comment: Why not try install mono (the .NET runtime for linux) and use [DroidExplorer](http://de.codeplex.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just talking about files, I'd take a look into [FTPSyncX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syncoorp.FTPSyncX_Trial) or [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). I can only talk for FTPSyncX, as I am using it myself -- but most of the following should be valid for both apps:

You can setup directory pairs (one on your device matching another on your PC), and have them sync bidirectionally or unidirectionally. You can configure the sync interval: globally, per server, or even per directory-pair. You can even tell it to only sync when you're in your Home WiFi, or only when you request it (via Widgets, from within the app, or even event-based controlled by [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

If this answer didn't catch your intention, feel free to comment, ask, or update your question :)

Comment: I accepted this answer, but you gave me 2 options. To make your answer useful to others, I just want to mention I used FTPSyncX and set it up as suggested

Comment: Glad to read, thank you! So just to make it complete: FTPSyncX has a [pro-version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syncoorp.FTPSyncX_Pro) as well. The trial mentioned in my answer is fully functional, but restricted in the number of servers/directories you can configure. So if the app works for you, but you need e.g. more directories to configure - that's where you can go (in fact, the Pro is what I am using). Btw: very responsive developer; e.g. the widgets and Tasker support was added on my request ;)